# Can't get the subnet id of azure using python

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I want to get the resource id of a subnet in a virtual network in azure using python, the command i have used is this line : subnets=network_client.subnets.get(resource_group,'XXX','XXX')

But what I get is an error: HttpResponseError: (InvalidApiVersionParameter) The api-version '2021-02-01' is invalid. The supported versions are '2021-04-01,2021-01-01,2020-10-01,2020-09-01,2020-08-01,2020-07-01,2020-06-01,2020-05-01,2020-01-01,2019-11-01,2019-10-01,2019-09-01,2019-08-01,2019-07-01,2019-06-01,2019-05-10,2019-05-01,2019-03-01,2018-11-01,2018-09-01,2018-08-01,2018-07-01,2018-06-01,2018-05-01,2018-02-01,2018-01-01,2017-12-01,2017-08-01,2017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.
I have tried different api versions but it's getting me errors.Any idea please ?
The version of azure-mgmt-network I used is 19.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have the below two models installed first before executing the script:

1. `pip install azure-mgmt-network`
2. `pip install azure-identity`

Then use the below script to get the `subnet-id` of specific subnet present in your subscription:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e00a844e059b"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
location = "West US 2"
virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
subnet_name = "acisubnet"
Subnet=network_client.subnets.get(resource_group_name, virtual_network_name, subnet_name)
print(Subnet.id)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note :** I am using pip version `pip 21.2.4 and (python 3.9)`. The pip models version that I am using are as below :

[image]

I am using the same network model version as you . But if you are still facing the issue then trying installing the new one i.e. [19.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-network/19.1.0/) .

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is like i have already done except i haven't pass it the name of the resource group, it was a wrong parameter. But I dont understand why it did return an error about the api version

Comment: @Houdakilani, Glad to be of help!! it use az-restapi's in the backend so if we don't pass or provide wrong parameters then it will give the error on api versions along with like we get in az cli ![image](https://i.imgur.com/Y6PWrRA.png)

Comment: do you have an idea how to solve this error please ?                                          (DnsNameLabelNotSupportedForInternalIPAddress) DNS name label for container group is only supported when IP Address type is public, current 'Private'.

Comment: if you are creating aci in a vnet then it won't be public , so , you use private and if private is set then you don't need to add dns label name. removing that should fix the issue

Comment: and also as mentioned in answer as well you cannot use a public image to create a aci in a subnet. you have to create a private image in acr (azure container registry ) and then use that using your server uri for acr and authenticating via username and password that you have set for the acr